# История изменений

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Мне нужно создать текстовый редактор, который, помимо всего прочего, будет хранить историю изменений(с возможностью двигаться вперёд и назад, ну в общем, как и в любом другом нормально редакторе.) Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать подобную функцию.... Я сначала хотел сохранять новую копию редактируемого документа после каждого изменения в нём, но тогда при большом размере файла, размер истории станет гигантским. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это всё организовать нормально на WinApi ?

Comment: [Command pattern][1]

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: Никогда не сталкивался, но может стоит попробовать хранить разницу между двумя состояниями. Аналогично системам контроля версий хранящим не файл целиком, а лишь "патч".

Comment: Какие-то интересные ответы и комментарии. Это последствия праздников или торжество ООП? На мой взгляд описанию соответствует любой редактор + система контроля версий. И то, и другое -- по вкусу. Только вот winapi там как-то сбоку.

Comment: @alexlz, какой-то интересный у вас комментарий. Это последствия праздников или просто невнимательно читаете вопрос?

Comment: @falstaf

      будет хранить историю изменений(с возможностью двигаться вперёд и назад, 

Это как раз функции системы контроля версий. Так что с прошедшим Вас Рождеством Христовым и с надвигающимся старым Новым годом.
Конечно, такой интеграции как в редакторских Undo/Redo не будет, но то, что @vvtvvtvvt планировал просто хранить разные версии целиком, перекрывается вполне.

Comment: ТС спрашивает, как программно в редакторах реализовываются операции undo/redo. Какое отношение к этому имеют VCS?

Comment: @falstaf Чего-то я не понимаю. Есть два утверждения. 1)

      Я сначала хотел сохранять новую копию редактируемого документа после каждого изменения в нём, но тогда при большом размере файла, размер истории станет гигантским.

2)

      ТС спрашивает, как программно в редакторах реализуются операции undo/redo. Какое отношение к этому имеют VCS?

Как из первого следует второе?

Answer (score 3):

Начните с чтения двух статей

- [Back/Forward и Undo/Redo в .NET-приложениях](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/backforward.xml)
- [Использование паттерна “Команда”](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/patterns/patterncommand.xml)

Да, там с уклоном в .NET, но какая разница? идея там явно описана и рассказано, как это делается.